# iOS, How to find selected row Of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to find selected `UITableViewCell` as following:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 

       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  }
    if   ([indexPath row] == [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row]) // i want to place value of selected row to populate the buttons 

        //([indexPath row] == 0)

        //(indexPath.row == ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) 

    {
        UIButton *AddComment = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; // custom means transparent it takes shape same with backgroup image

        [AddComment addTarget:self 
                       action:@selector(TestBtns:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        // [AddComment setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        AddComment.frame = CGRectMake(9.0, 128.0, 96.0, 26.0);

        [cell.contentView addSubview:AddComment];

        UIImage *buttonAddComment = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addcomment.png"];

        [AddComment setBackgroundImage:buttonAddComment forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:AddComment]; 


    }
```

How to achieve this, can you please guide me, where I'm doing Mistake.

Comment: Where is **didselectrowatindexpath** method ???

Comment: where did you want to fine the selected cell of UITableview..? at **didselectrowatindexpath** or button TouchUiInside Method?

Comment: Please also check the line "if([indexPath row] == [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath])". Here you are comparing a NSInteger with a UITableViewCell!

Answer (score 108):

> Objective C

```
 NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

> Swift code

```
let indexPathForSelectedRow = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

Comment: why dont you accept this as the correct answer? @pratap Manish Bhadoria

Comment: Methinks @PratapManishBhadoria forgot to check this answer.

Comment: @TaimurAjmal can u be speciffic.It was working as u can see from the upvotes

Comment: @SurajKThomas, oh yeah it works and is the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 16):

Use this **delegate** method of `UITableView`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row); // you can see selected row number in your console;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

in UITableViewDataSource delegate there is a method **- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**.

It returns NSIndexPath object which caontains both the selected section and selected row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"Selected section>> %d",indexPath.section);
    NSLog(@"Selected row of section >> %d",indexPath.row);
}
```

make sure to set datasource of tableview before using it otherwise this method won't be called

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int a = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"index: %i",a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the built-in method that will help you determine which cell has been selected.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // you can use "indexPath" to know what cell has been selected as the following
    NSLog(@"Selected row is %@", indexPath);
}
```

and by the way the method is already given when you create TableViewController, you probably just  have to uncomment it.

Hope you find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is not to get the index of the table view cell clicked but to know which cell is clicked.

To know this at the time of assigning each cell assign the **indexpath.row** value as the tag of the cell created then on clicked take the table view as the parent and try to get its subview(cell) with that tag

**[Tableview view with tag:indexpath.row]**