# Found nil when trying to read from table cell in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a problem I do not understand since I am new to iPhone app programming and Swift.

I have a TableView in Swift which I use to display some results on. I have added a button to each cell such that the user can choose different cells and then press delete in order to delete the results shown in the cell.

For just a few number of results that worked just fine but now I have started to get nil-exception.

The program crashes in the function getIndexToDelete when I try to get the cell for a certain row.

Here is the code where I handle the table:

```
import UIKit

class DailyResultTable: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,      UITableViewDelegate {
var results = Results()
var yearShownIndex = 0
var monthShownIndex = 0
var dayShownIndex = 0
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var DeleteButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 //   self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "StatisticBackground")!)

}

// DataSource
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableview: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   // return (self.results?.getDayList(yearShownIndex, posMonth: monthShownIndex).count)!
    print("return number of rows")
    if (results.getYearList().count > 0 ){
        if (results.getMonthList(yearShownIndex).count > 0){
            if (results.getDayList(yearShownIndex, posMonth: monthShownIndex).count > dayShownIndex){
            return (results.getDayList(yearShownIndex, posMonth: monthShownIndex)[dayShownIndex].results.count)
            }
        }
    }
    print("No numbers to show return 0")
    return 0;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DayResultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultTableCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    //cell.ResultField.text =  String((results?.getDayList(yearShownIndex, posMonth: monthShownIndex)[row].day)!) + "/" + String((results?.getMonthList(yearShownIndex)[monthShownIndex].month)!)
    let res = results.getDayList(yearShownIndex, posMonth: monthShownIndex)[dayShownIndex].results[row].result
    let maxRes = results.getDayList(yearShownIndex, posMonth: monthShownIndex)[dayShownIndex].results[row].maxresult
    let discipline = results.getDayList(yearShownIndex, posMonth: monthShownIndex)[dayShownIndex].results[row].discipline
    let text1 = String(res) + "/"
    let text2 =  String(maxRes)
    let text3 = " - " + discipline
    let text = text1 + text2 + text3
    print(text)
    cell.ResultField.text = text
    return cell
}


// Delegate
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
@IBAction func CheckBox(sender: UIButton) {
    let image = UIImage(named: "Selected") as UIImage!
    let selected = sender.selected
    sender.selected = !selected
    sender.setImage(image, forState: .Selected)
}

func getIndexToDelete()->[Int]{
    var indices = [Int]()

    for i in 0..<tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0){
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
         // Here does the program crash
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ResultTableCell
        if (cell.CheckBoxButton.selected){
            indices += [i]

    }
    }
    return indices
}

@IBAction func DeletePressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let deleteIndices = getIndexToDelete()
    var goback = false;
    var count = 0;
    for index in deleteIndices{
        print("Count: " + String(count))
        results.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months[monthShownIndex].day[dayShownIndex].results.removeAtIndex(index-count)
        count += 1
        print(String((results.getDayList(yearShownIndex, posMonth: monthShownIndex)[dayShownIndex].results.count)));

    }
    loadView()
    results.recreatePlainResult()
    results.saveResults()

    if (results.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months[monthShownIndex].day[dayShownIndex].results.count == 0){
        print(String(results.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months[monthShownIndex].day.count))
        results.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months[monthShownIndex].day.removeAtIndex(dayShownIndex)
        results.recreatePlainResult()
        results.saveResults()
        print(String(results.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months[monthShownIndex].day.count))
        goback = true
    }
    if (results.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months[monthShownIndex].day.count == 0){
        results.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months.removeAtIndex(monthShownIndex)
        results.recreatePlainResult()
        results.saveResults()
        goback = true
    }
    if (results.ListResults[yearShownIndex].months.count == 0){
        results.ListResults.removeAtIndex(monthShownIndex)
        results.recreatePlainResult()
        results.saveResults()
        goback = true
    }
    if (goback){
       // return;
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}

}
```

Here is the ResultTableCell:

```
import UIKit

class ResultTableCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var ResultField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var CheckBoxButton: UIButton!

}
```

I can of course put `let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ResultTableCell`inside an if-clause, but then other strange things happens.

Comment: if you want to determine which button was pressed in the tableview I reccomend that you set button.tag = indexPath.row ... this way you know exactly what button you pressed without this horrible thing...set the tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for [Create Custom Checkboxes in Swift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hgfNfG7EKQ) In case anyone else need it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `!`.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns `UITableViewCell?` and can be nil if the row isn't visible when you make the call.

Check whether you actually got a cell at all using `if let` before casting it to your expected object type.

Comment: Ok, but how can the row not be visible? If I change and use if let instead, then it works if I select some rows and press delete. The tableview updates and only the remaining results are shown. But when I select a new result and delete that, all table rows turns blank.

Comment: I don't know your specific case but, for example, if you show seven rows at a time in your UI and there are ten results, then three or those results have no associated cell.  (You might want to print the actual number of rows you're returning from `numberOfRowsInSection`.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here, let's take them one at a time:

1. The crash is from forcing the `nil` value through the `!` that part should be obvious.
2. The `for` loop goes from `0` through to the number of rows, but `UITableViewCell` instances get recycled, so that can't work.
3. The checkbox selection is not the standard iOS table cell selection but something more custom

If you were using the built-in selection behavior of `UITableView`you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18637332) method.

If you want to continue using your custom checkbox selection, than probably the easiest way to do that is to listen for the selection change and build up the `NSIndexPath` as things are selected.

Afterward when the <kbd>delete</kbd> button is pressed you will have a pre-built index ready to delete and you won't have to loop to search for what is selected.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments! As I understand it, the standard function is for selecting for the entire row? I guess it is more intuitive to just press the button if one wants to delete it?

Comment: Selection is for one row or multiple rows.  `NSIndexPath` can have more than one thing in it https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/